# Is it possible to specify more than one type hint for a parameter?

Tags: php, type-hinting

Is there a way to add more than one type hinting to a method? For example, foo(param) must receive a instance of string OR bar OR baz.

Comment: Type hinting doesn't support string scalars; just pointing that out.

Comment: @Qix We should now mention that [PHP does support scalar type hinting as of PHP 7.0.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Answer (score 26):

That is not possible to enforce (except inside the method). You can only provide a single type hint, and only to objects/interfaces and arrays (since PHP 5.1).

You can/should however document it in your method, i.e:

```
/**
 * @param string|Bar|Baz $param1
 */
function foo($param1);
```

Answer (score 16):

This is one use of [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).  If you want to be sure that the object has a `->foobar($baz)` method, you could expect an interface:

```
interface iFooBar {
    public function foobar($baz);
}

class Foo implements iFooBar {
    public function foobar($baz) { echo $baz; }
}
class Bar implements iFooBar {
    public function foobar($baz) { print_r($baz); }
}

function doSomething(iFooBar $foo) {
    $foo->foobar('something');
}
```

Then, when calling, these will work:

```
doSomething(new Foo());
doSomething(new Bar());
```

These will not:

```
doSomething(new StdClass());
doSomething('testing');
```

Comment: Pretty cool! There are SPL types too (experimental): http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php

Comment: @joao: SPLTypes won't work on 5.3 (They use deprecated c calls).  Plus the last update was in 2008, so it's pretty safe to say it's not current...

Answer (score 11):

At the time of this writing there is no support for multiple explicit types. You have to rely on documentation and PHP's dynamic type system.

However, I do have a mostly incomplete proposal for [union types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types). It is targeting 7.NEXT (at the time of this writing this is 7.1) or 8 (whichever comes first).

Here is a simple example of something that I think would be very valuable: `array | Traversable`:

```
function map(callable $fn, array|Traversable $input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        yield $key => $fn($value);
    }
}
```

---

Unfortunately the RFC did not pass; however for the specific type `array|Traversable` there is now an `iterable` type which is exactly that.

Comment: Your proposal has been rejected. Is there any future plan for this in PHP8?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think it's worth pursuing, but personally I will be working on other features.

Answer (score 7):

[Type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) only allows for one hint per parameter (and also, the hint needs to be `array` or a class name, you can't hint `string`), but you can do this by checking the type of the param within your function, using [`get_class`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
function foo($param)
{
  if (!(is_string($param) || in_array(get_class($param), array("Bar", "Baz")))
  {
    // invalid type for $param!
  }
}
```

You could even use [`trigger_error`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) to have it fail with a PHP error (like it would if a type hint failed) if you wanted.

Comment: I'd suggest throwing a `InvalidArgumentException`, so that you can at least attempt to recover from the error...

Comment: @ircmaxell I was just demonstrating how the OP *could* replicate how type hints work.

Comment: I'm not saying not to `trigger_error`.  It all depends on your style (and there's nothing wrong with using `trigger_error`).  I prefer exceptions, so I use `InvalidArgumentException`.  If your goal is to mimic type hints, then by all means trigger a fatal error...

Comment: @ircmaxell Agreed; I personally wouldn't use `trigger_error` for this either :)

Comment: Update: Since PHP 7 string (and bool, int, float) is a valid type hint.

Comment: Update: PHP 7.1 added [nullable hint types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) and PHP 7.2 adds the [object hint type](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object-typehint).

Answer (score 6):

Fantastic question. It applies to both IDE documentation and PHP 5 [Type Hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).
You have to remember that in OO [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism) is your friend.

If you create a base class and extend them, your type hint will be base class... all extended class will work. See example below.

```
//
$test = new DUITest();

//  Calls below will work because of polymorphism
echo $test->test(new Molecule()) . '<br/>';
echo $test->test(new Vodka()) . '<br/>';
echo $test->test(new Driver()) . '<br/>';
echo $test->test(new Car()) . '<br/>';

//  Will not work because different data type
echo $test->test(new Pig()) . '<br/>';
echo $test->test(new Cop()) . '<br/>';
echo $test->test('test') . '<br/>';
echo $test->test(array()) . '<br/>';



/**
 * Class to test 
 */
class DUITest {

    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Using type-hinting
     * 
     * See below link for more information
     * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php
     * 
     * @param Molecule|Car|Driver|Vodka $obj 
     */
    public function test(Molecule $obj) {
        echo $obj;
    }

}

/**
 * Base Class
 */
class Molecule {

    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Outputs name of class of current object
     * @return <type> 
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return get_class($this);
    }

}

class Car extends Molecule {}

class Driver extends Molecule {}

class Vodka extends Molecule {}

class Pig {}
class Cop extends Pig{}
```

Comment: cool, but what's about null? It's a usual practice to return something or null