# Symfony's documentation Implies that Multiple Type-Hinting is Possible. Why?

Tags: php, symfony, type-hinting

I had assumed that multiple type-hinting wasn't possible. However, I saw this constructor in the [Symfony API Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.html) documentation.

```
__construct(array $options = array(), AbstractProxy|NativeSessionHandler|SessionHandlerInterface|null $handler = null, MetadataBag $metaBag = null)
```

For the second parameter, it makes it seemthat multiple types are possible. Can someone explain what I am seeing?

Comment: @watcher I read that post first. I'm not asking if it possible, I assumed it wasn't. I'm asking why the code string makes it seem like it is possible. Do you have any suggestions on editing the post to better reflect that?

Comment: @watcher Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a good question, though the answer is its not actually a type hint in the language sense. More of the documentation

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7c026bb33e8ca96b285402f7fe7ae27a04a74ea9/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L99

Is where it is defined in source, with no type hint

```
public function __construct(array $options = array(), $handler = null, MetadataBag $metaBag = null)
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7c026bb33e8ca96b285402f7fe7ae27a04a74ea9/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L353

Is where the functionality exists, where it simply checks with instanceof for all of the type hints listed in the documentation

```
 if (!$saveHandler instanceof AbstractProxy &&
            !$saveHandler instanceof NativeSessionHandler &&
            !$saveHandler instanceof \SessionHandlerInterface &&
            null !== $saveHandler) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Must be instance of AbstractProxy or NativeSessionHandler; implement \SessionHandlerInterface; or be null.');
        }
```

These hints are used by IDE's for consistency checking code, as Pazi Mentioned in the comments

More information can be found here

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html

> To be able to track which types may be used in a value you can use the
>   pipe, or OR, (|) operator to separate each type that the associated
>   value may be.
>
> In the following example a method, or function, will return either a
>   string or null as value:
>
> /** @return string|null */ Most IDEs will recognize this format as
>   well and offer auto-completion

Comment: I was about to answer pretty much the same thing, that according to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840094/is-it-possible-to-specify-more-than-one-type-hint-for-a-parameter) having multiple type-hints is not allowed (I could not find a relevant quote from the docs).  I think the symfony documentation is only using that nomenclature for 'aesthetic' reasons.

Comment: The multiple "type hint" are defined in the docblock and are not for aesthetic reason. IDEs can evaluate the docblock and warn if a given class is not in the scope if the docblock type

Comment: It did not occur to me that the docs were reflecting the source Thank you.

Comment: @Pazi OP seems to be specifically asking about the online documentation, and not the docblock, but that is a good point.

Comment: The online docs are derived from the docblocks in the source, not the concrete type hinting in php function declaration.